# label of repeat password symfony 2.3

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to create a form with Symfony but I have a problem with a repeated field

```
->add('password', 'repeated', array(
    'type'=> 'password',
    'first_name' => $translator->trans('global.password'),
    'second_name' => $translator->trans('register.confirm')
))
```

I have no problems if there is just a word in first_name or second_name but if there is a space or a point I have this error:

```
The name "register.confirm" contains illegal characters. Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":").
```

Is there a solution to set spaces or points ?

Thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first_name` and `second_name` are not labels for the fields. These are **names** of that fields. And field names should contain nothing except **letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":")**.
For more information look at the isValidName method source code: http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.html#method_isValidName

To set **labels** for both fields use `first_options` and `second_options`.

```
->add('password', 'repeated', array(
    'type'=> 'password',
    'first_options' => array('label' => $translator->trans('global.password')),
    'second_options' => array('label' =>$translator->trans('register.confirm'))
))
```

[Repeated Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html)